# Try/Catch & If Statement Weirdness

Tags: php, if-statement, try-catch

Running into an issue when using an if/else statement within a try/block.

```
try {
    $response = $flickr->callPhotos($content, $limit);
    if($response['stat'] === 'fail'){
        throw new Exception('Please authorize this application.');
    } else {
        --> Code that should not be parsed <--
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When running this code for some reason the error is thrown correctly, the error is echoed correctly, but then the "Code that should not be parsed" is also being allowed to run generating more errors.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, should definitely stop after catching the exception.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal **executable** test case that reproduces the problem?

Comment: How will it know where to find the catch block without parsing the code in between?

Comment: Works when mocked: http://codepad.org/cag8uTDm

Comment: You'd be better of replacing the if..else statement with another exception statement (i.e. nested exceptions)

Comment: @deceze - Actually it doesn't: http://codepad.org/3Orh1MRB

Comment: @Tomm As I said: *when mocked [up]*. Hence my question for an *executable* sample from the OP.

Comment: Well that's really the exact code, outside the class function call which returns the $response array, and the parsing code that's contains a for/each statement thats throwing the additional errors.

I just figured that the else statement would be skipped. If there's another way of forcing the script to skip the rest of the code, while parsing everything that comes after the else statement, that would be perfect.

Comment: I doubt `--> Code that should not be parsed <--` is the exact code. What kind of errors are you talking about? The details are important here, don't omit them.

Comment: The additional error is being thrown from within the "Code that should not be parsed" --> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

My question is why is that even being allowed to run it the IF statement is true?

Comment: Again, works fine when mocked: http://codepad.org/ouQAzXqr

Comment: Slapping myself. deceze you were correct; it was working. I was mistakenly calling the instance of code twice; the first instance was validating correctly, but the second was not due to a code variation. Lol, thanks.